# file_get_contents with spaces in URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents, spaces

I have an issue where even if I replace the spaces to %20 and get this content the ultimate url the browser gets turns the "%20" into "%2520"

Here's my code, any suggestions to get this to work? it seems easy but I'm stuck :/

```
<?php
//$_GET['song'] will contain a song name with spaces
$song = str_replace(array("%20", "&", "?" , "/"), array(" ", "", "", ""), $_GET['song']);

// I use this to check how the GET 'song' looks after the str_replace
$list = "http://www.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=" . $song . "&for=fullt";
echo "list url is " . $list . "<hr>";

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=" . str_replace(" ", "%20", $song) . "&for=fullt");

echo $content;
?>
```

if you go to http://webservices.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?q=red%20hot%20chili%20peppers&for=fullt The result should output a list of lyric codes.

When i go to my website /?song=red hot chili peppers  , it too converts spaces to %20 's but if it seems the browser converts the %'s to %25.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Always use `urlencode()` for a single parameter, or `http_build_query()` for multiple parameters in the HTTP query string:

```
$song = $_GET['song']);
$url = "http://www.lyrdb.com/lookup.php?for=fullt&q=";
$content = file_get_contents($url . urlencode($song));
```

or

```
$url = "http://www.lyrdb.com/lookup.php";
$query = ['for' => 'fullt', 'q' => $song];
$content = file_get_contents($url . '?' . http_build_query($query));
```

Comment: THANK YOU Cheery !!!!
(there's a ) after the first line, but other than that THANKS! When I tried using urlencode and htmlentities together but that caused problems. I can't thank you enough!!

Comment: @LearningDaily  `htmlentities` and analogous functions should be used when you want to output something into the page with the data received from the user. it helps to prevent XSS attacks. `urlencode` is needed to convert URL's query parameters to the RFC standard of data transfer through the GET method.

Comment: @Cheery as you can see, htmlentities is a bit confusing here, so I took the liberty to remove it, while adding an explanation and another option. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);

$url = "http://www.index.com?data=";

echo file_get_contents($url . urlencode($data));
```